# How to prove or disprove $\int_1^\infty \operatorname{arccot}(\cot(\pi x))/(\pi x^2) dx = 1 - \gamma$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $\gamma$ be Euler constant.

According to Maple 13:

$$ \int_1^\infty \operatorname{arccot}(\cot(\pi x))/(\pi x^2) dx = 1 - \gamma $$

How to prove or disprove this?

Numerically get approximation which is not
good at high precision, possibly due to numerical
instability.

Comment: does this mean Maple is better than Mathematica?

Comment: @SantoshLinkha don't know, what Mathematica says about it?

Comment: Mathematica can't compute it ... probably due to $\cot(\pi x)$ term there.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I suspect this is true, but don't see how Maple derived this...

Comment: Mathematica 9.0.1.0 states the integral under consideration diverges. This is not true because the numerator of the integrand is nonnegative and less than or equal to $\pi$. The Maple code $$ int(arccot(cot(Pi*x))/(Pi*x^2), x = 1 .. 1000, numeric, epsilon = 0.1e-2)$$ outputs $0.4222844184 $, confirming $1-\gamma .$

Comment: yes that is true, but $\cot(\pi x)$ has singularity at $x=n$, probably it's considering that. may be it's time to p****e Maple 13

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the value of the integral depends on the choice of branch cut for the arccosine. Maple and Mathematica make different choices for that branch cut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numerator represents a sawtooth curve, so, the integral can be written as:

\begin{align*}
  \int_{1}^{\infty} \, \frac{\operatorname{arccot}{\cot(\pi x)}}{\pi x^2} \, dx &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{i}^{i+1} \, \frac{x-i}{x^2}\, dx \\
    &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log{(i+1)}-\log{i}-\frac{1}{i+1} \\
    &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \log{(n+1)}-H_{n+1} + 1 \\
    &= 1-\gamma
\end{align*}

**Update**:

In general, for $b>1$ and $b \ne 2$,

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \, \frac{\operatorname{arccot}{\cot(\pi x)}}{\pi x^b} \, dx = 
\frac{1}{b-2}-\frac{\zeta(b-1)}{b-1}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Does this work for denominators like $\pi x^4$ or $\pi x^{3/2}$?

Comment: Yes, it does. When denominator is $\pi x^4$, integral is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\zeta(3)}{3}$, I was trying for the closed form for the $\pi x^{3/2}$, couldn't get it yet.

Comment: For s>-1 the integral with denominator \pi x^{s+1} is simple function of \zeta(s).

Comment: For s>2, it's easy to see that $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \, \frac{\operatorname{arccot}{\cot(\pi x)}}{\pi x^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{s-2}-\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{s-1}$$ For $2>s>1$, is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: gar, this is related to the fractional part {x} of x. Check the identity and use the integral for zeta: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820111/integral-with-fractional-part-int-01-operatornamearccoshx-dx

Comment: sage 6.2 on linux:  `def fra(x):  return 1/2-arctan(cot(pi*x))/pi` `integrate(fra(arccosh(x)),x,0,1)`

Comment: Do you have opinion about the other question? (The SE software suggest chat to avoid clutter, chat is OK for me).

Comment: I think achille hui has got it right, my opinion would be the same. (I may not respond in real time, we may delete the comments later if we consider it unimportant)

Comment: Single integral giving the same bug in two CASes is not common IMHO.

Comment: RE: your edit about zeta(b). It might be possible this is true for complex $b$ too for $\Re b > -1$.

Comment: (1) It may have to do something with defining the fractional part like that. Even wolframalpha, in turn, mathematica gives i as the answer.  (2) I think the integral diverges for $b\le 1$. It may hold good for complex $b$ as well, if the integral converges. For real values, I do numerical integration to check. I don't know how to get numerical integrals for complex numbers.

Comment: Might be wrong about b= -1, it might be b=1. sage's module `mpmath` does complex integrals via `quad`, not sure it makes sense (don't get numerical support).

Comment: IIRC I saw somewhere the integral is valid for complex b, not sure. For the $i$ integral Maple returns $i$ with its builtin frac().

Comment: You are welcome. Saw the fractional part and the zeta integral on Mathoverflow. There is connection to transforming sum to integral:  I(x)=floor(x)=x-{x}=x-F(x). And maybe \sum_n=a^b f(n) ?= \int_a^b f(I(n))

Comment: The `quadts` worked nicely when floor() was used. I could see that the formula works well for complex numbers also. E.g. `quadts(lambda x:(x-floor(x))/(x**(mpc(3/2.,-3))),[1,inf],verbose=1,maxdegree=10)`

Comment: gar, Thanks for `quadts`, I failed will only `quad`. (1) Does $F(x)$ works instead of {x} in zeta? (2) Does the integral numerically vanishes at zeta zeros - the n-th zeta zero is `mpmath.zetazero(n)`.

Comment: You are welcome, and `quad` is actually `quadts` by default. (1) I did not understand what $F(x)$ refers to here. (2) The real part of zetazero(n) appears to be 0.5, for which the integral likely does not converge.

Comment: Good morning. Sorry I wasn't clear. (1) F(x) is the fractional part in terms of \cot from the other question (2) From your update you have zeta(s)=f( integral(s+1)) and for Re s = 1/2, Re (s+1) = 3/2 so the integral converges. When computed with the integral (possibly with F(s) ) does zeta vanishes at zeros?

Comment: Good morning. (1) You mean to say that we use `acot(cot(x))` instead of `x-floor(x)` in the integral? The `quad` function had problem with the former, answer wasn't close. (2) Yes, the zeta vanishes, and the integral is 1/(s-2)

Comment: (1) Not exactly acot(), this one $F(x) =\{x\}= 1/2-{\frac {1/2\,\pi -{\it arccot} \left( \cot \left( \pi \,x \right)  \right) }{\pi }}$. (2) The exact mpmath code is as in your previous comment with quadts(,maxdegree=10) ?

Comment: (1) Yes, that one.. Doesn't work in mpmath. (2) Yeah, but note that it takes a longer time for complex vaues.

Comment: Weird F(x) doesn't work... mpmath and sage have bugs. This divergent series returns $-2$:  `mpmath.nsum(lambda n:  mpmath.mpf(2)**n,[1,mpmath.inf])`

Comment: Nice catch, looks like it blindly calculates the geometric sum. Sage correctly suggests it's divergent `sum(2^x,x,1,oo)`

Comment: gar, just a challenge ;). Using your integral Update for zeta, can you prove using the integral closed form for zeta'(1/2)/zeta(1/2). The answer is: (gamma/2+3*log(2)/2+log(pi)/2+pi/4)

Comment: Nice result! I'll tell if I get it.