# Integral with fractional part $\int_0^1 \{\operatorname{arccosh(x)}\} dx = ?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$
and for complex $x,\{x\}=\{\Re x\}+ i\{\Im x\}$

Let $$ A= \int_0^1 \{\operatorname{arccosh(x)}\} dx $$

What is $A$?

According to Maple 13, symbolically $A = i$.

Using the identity

$$ F(x) =\{x\}= 1/2-{\frac {1/2\,\pi -{\it arccot} \left( \cot \left( \pi \,x \right)  \right) }{\pi }} $$

in sage numerically got $A = 1 + i$ and symbolically got $A=i$.

Integer is somewhat surprising to me.

For similar integral in both sage and Maple got:

$$ \int_0^1 \{\operatorname{arcsinh(x)}\} dx = 1-\ln  \left( \sqrt {2}-1 \right) -\sqrt {2}$$

Comment: Might I ask what leads you to consider this integral in the first place??

Comment: @Stahl just curious and surprised by the integer.

Comment: The value of $A$ cannot be $i$ or $1 + i$. i.e both of them are wrong. Since the real and imaginary part of the integrand takes value from $[0,1)$, we must have $0 \le \Re A, \Im A < 1$.

Comment: @user114872 : For this integral also, could get mpmath working, no luck for symbolic integration though. `quadts(lambda x:(acosh(x)-floor(acosh(x))),[0,1],verbose=1,maxdegree=10)` which is close to $i\, (1-\cos{1})$

Comment: @gar your command doesn't work for me with mpmath from sage 6.2 on Linux. get $nan+1j$ and error estimate $1$.

Comment: @user114872 : You mean the command above ? That's strange, it's working on sage 6.1.1. Did you change anything?

Comment: @gar it works now, might have done something wrong. Thank you. The result is indeed close, though not enough close at high precision.

Comment: @user114872 : You're welcome. Yeah, the precision is quite low.

Comment: @gar the second integral with arcsinh works numerically with both quad(floor()) and F(x), agreeing with the symbolic expression.

Comment: @user114872 : Yes, but see that arcsinh(x)<1 when x<1. So, F(x) doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @gar F(x) works often for real x. It worked for the other question for \gamma and zeta.

Comment: @user114872 : I meant to say that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \{\operatorname{arcsinh(x)}\} dx = \int_0^1 \operatorname{arcsinh(x)} dx $

Answer (score 3):

For any $x \in (0,1]$, parametrize it as $\cos\theta$ for some $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have

$$\cosh^{-1}(x) = \log(x + \sqrt{x^2-1}) = \log(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) = \log e^{i\theta} = i\theta = i\cos^{-1}(x)$$

As a result,

$$\int_0^1\big\{\cosh^{-1}(x)\big\}dx
= i\int_0^1 \big\{\cos^{-1}(x)\big\}dx
= i\left[\int_0^1 \cos^{-1}(x) dx - \int_0^1 \big\lfloor\cos^{-1}(x)\big\rfloor dx\right]$$
Notice

$$\int_0^1 \cos^{-1}(x) dx = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad
\big\lfloor\cos^{-1}(x)\big\rfloor = 
\begin{cases}
1,& x \in [0,\cos 1]\\
\\
0,& x \in (\cos 1, 1]
\end{cases}$$
We get
$$ 
\int_0^1\big\{\cosh^{-1}(x)\big\}dx = i\left[1 - \int_0^{\cos 1} dx\right] = i(1-\cos 1)
$$